# VBA to copy formula across variable rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm entering a value in the last blank cell (as I can't do the last row in a column) due to other data being there. I was to add the sum of all the above cells to each column.
The number of columns is variable as is the number of names

I've been able to add the relevant formula but I can't get it to copy across in the same way my other code did.
This is the line with the error, to copy to the last used column, everything else works except this bit.

```
Range("O" & nextfree).AutoFill Range("O" & nextfree, Cells("O" & nextfree, lastcolumn))
```

I get a run type error 13, Type mis-match.

The full code is here

```
Sub addrow()

'Checks the number of users then adds them to the active sheet section

Dim rowsToAdd As Integer
Dim lastcolumn As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Refs")
Set w1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Active events")
  
    With ws
    lastRow = Sheets("Refs").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = Sheets("Active events").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    MsgBox lastRow - 1
    MsgBox lastcolumn
    End With

With ws1
Rows("5:5").Resize(lastRow - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown ' minus 2 to account for header row and also existing text in row 4
End With

Worksheets("Refs").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy Worksheets("Active events").Range("M4")

Range("O4:O" & lastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUMIF($C$14:$C$5032,$M4,O$14:O$5032)"
Range("O4:O" & lastRow + 2).AutoFill Range("O4", Cells(lastRow + 2, lastcolumn))


'Find the next blank cell in the names range and adds totals and the sum value to all columns

nextfree = Range("M4:M" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("M" & nextfree).Value = "Total"
Range("O" & nextfree).Value = "=SUM(O4:O" & nextfree - 1 & ")"

'Problem code here
Range("O" & nextfree).AutoFill Range("O" & nextfree, Cells("O" & nextfree, lastcolumn))


End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A1")`, `Cells(1,1)`, & `Cells(1, "A")`, are important to keep straight, and each reference the same cell location.  You have written `Cells("O" & nextfree, lastcolumn)`, which doesn't fit the model.

Comment: Do you know how I could amend this to copy it across. As the starting range can always change I can't enter a fixed row number, only a fixed column.

Comment: so, i just had to remove the "O" reference to make.  Range("O" & nextfree).AutoFill Range("O" & nextfree, Cells( nextfree, lastcolumn)). Been looking at that for ages trying to see what i was doing wrong. Thanks Cyril